# SonataAdminBundle inheritance issue

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, sonata-admin

I'm facing an issue about the inheritance with `SonataAdminBundle`

I have 2 entities that linked each other : **AbstractPerson** & **Vehicle** 
and 2 entities that inherit of **AbstractPerson**: **Person** & **Society**

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * AbstractPerson
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "society" = "Society"})
 */
abstract class AbstractPerson
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vehicle", mappedBy="owner")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $vehicles;
}

/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Person extends AbstractPerson
{
}

/**
 * Society
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Society extends AbstractContact
{
}
```

And there is my **Vehicle** entity:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Vehicle
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="vehicle")
 */
class Vehicle
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AbstractPerson" ,inversedBy="vehicles")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $owner;
}
```

SonataAdminBundle allows us to handle inheritance between entities with *setSubClasses* method sets in the admin.yml :

```
services:
    sonata.admin.abstract_contact:
        class: Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\Admin\AbstractPersonAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Vehicle Manager", label: "AbstractPerson", label_catalogue: "messages" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\Entity\AbstractPerson
        - ~
    calls:
        - [setSubClasses, [{society: Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\Entity\Society, person: Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\Entity\Person}]] # Here the method that handles inheritance
```

Now I can create *Person* & *Society* but the problem is in the *Vehicle* form. From this form I can create a person but Sonata want to **instanciate an AbstractPerson** (an abstract class)

```
Cannot initialize abstract class: Foo\Bundle\BarBundle\Entity\AbstractPerson
```

If anyone can help me to instanciate a person or a society instead of an abstract person I will be delighted!

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!

Comment: You're almost done, but you made a design mistake in your admin.

Comment: Sonata Admins must represent Concrete entities, so you must never create admins based on abstract entities. I will provide an answer to fix this now

Comment: @BwaBwa: where in Sonata are you encountering that error?

Comment: @MatthewWebb the problem is solved. See pull request [#2917](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/2917)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now solved on their end.

See [#2917](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/2917)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr:

1 admin for Person 
1 admin for Society 
1 admin (optional) for Person + Society

## Long story:

The only flaw in your logic is the "sonata.admin.abstract_contact".
From an architecture point of view, Person and Society are two completely different entities, and the Single Table Inheritance you're using here is only meant to help your implementation look cleaner

In order to fix this, you need TWO separate admins, one for each entity.
And if you want a joined admin in which to manage BOTH entities simultaneously, you need to create a THIRD admin service which has two fields, both of "sonata_admin_type", in which you include the two admins.

Comment: From my development it seems that admin classes can represent abstract models, as long as `setSubClasses` is called as in BwaBwa's example.
However I find whether or not it actually works is often quite fraught.